# What format is this file written on?

Tags: java, parsing, format

I'm messing around with Auctionator (a WoW addon for the auction house). My application is still in development but out of curious i want to know the name for this format.

D:\Blizzard\World of Warcraft\WTF\Account\54621418#1\SavedVariables\Auctionator.lua

```
AUCTIONATOR_PRICE_DATABASE = {
    ["__dbversion"] = 4,
    ["Ragnaros_Horde"] = {
        ["Kraken's Eye of Agility"] = {
            ["mr"] = 6019998,
            ["cc"] = 3,
            ["H2935"] = 6019998,
            ["id"] = "153708:0:0:0:0",
            ["sc"] = 1,
        },
        ["Tidespray Linen Pants of the Harmonious"] = {
            ["mr"] = 2930810,
            ["sc"] = 1,
            ["id"] = "154689:0:0:0:1715",
            ["L2926"] = 2930810,
            ["H2926"] = 19698294,
            ["cc"] = 4,
        },
    },
}
```

I ended up parsing the file with lots of indexOf(..) and Patters and Matchers because i couldn't find this format anywhere. Here's a screenshot of the application if you wanna see it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A LUA file is a source code file written in Lua, a light-weight programming language designed for extending applications. It can be compiled into a program using an ANSI C compiler. 
Your file looks like a `table/config` details 
More you can have a look on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)